# How can I access this helper function in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm using [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/) for pushing notifications to subscribed clients to my users. In my application.html.haml I have:

```
...
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
= subscribe_to "/#{@user.access_token}/notifications"
...
```

The subscribe_to helper works fine in development. When deployed to production, the following error is logged:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `subscribe_to' for #<#<Class:0x00000001f372e8>:0x00000001fded90>):
    5:     = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'all'
    6:     = include_gon(:init => true)
    7:     = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    8:     = subscribe_to "/#{@user.access_token}/notifications"
    9:     = csrf_meta_tags
    10: 
    11:   %body
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__1867651381877570337_14592040'
```

How can I get access to this helper method in my production environment?

Comment: Did you `bundle install` in production after adding it to the gemfile?

Comment: Yes, my deploy script runs bundle install

Comment: what is the version of Rails are you running ?

Comment: Currently running rails 3.2.7

Comment: Any chance that you put `gem "private_pub"` into a group in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: private_pub is root level, right under the rails gem and thin server gem

Comment: It looks like somehow gem is not getting loaded possible chances can be either `gem` is not a part of `Gemfile.lock` or either in `development` group or server has not been restarted after installing bundle. If you are using `passenger` then make sure to run `touch tmp/restart.txt`

Comment: private_pub and faye are in the Gemfile.lock file. I'm using unicorn as my app server and haven't had any problems with new gems being added to the codebase. The only group I have is assets and private_pub is outside of this group.

Comment: Do private_pub work in the console on production, Can you create a client and subscribe?

Comment: @mguymon I'm able to run ``PrivatePub.publish_to("/test", :message => "Test")`` no problem in the rails console. AFAIK there's no subscribe_to outside of the JS. I'm unable to run that command in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an error with loading the PrivatePub engine. If you look at [engine.rb](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/blob/master/lib/private_pub/engine.rb), you see it is adding the PrivatePub view helpers as part of the init. Might be a bug if it is loading for the development, but not production environment.

Try and create a config/initializers that loads the PrivatePub helpers manually:

```
require 'private_pub/view_helpers'
ActionView::Base.send :include, PrivatePub::ViewHelpers
```

Comment: I'm unable to access private_pub/view_helpers in the initializer. I get a LoadError

Comment: Something is wrong with your production gems. I just created a new Rails 3 project and tested the initializer, it loads without issue. If the require is failing, it means the private_pub gem is not loaded. What command do you use to run your rails server?

Comment: yes it looks like my Debian server fails with this, but running Ubuntu on a different server hardware stack worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is your deploy script starting Faye's rackup file?
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production

Comment: yes, I can load the faye.js file just fine. When I deploy the rails application it can't find the method subscribe_to